# Button padding problems in firefox/opera

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my Buttons in HTML. When I place button in Opera it is in center (vertically), but in firefox, The button text appears a little bit down than Opera's, which ruins my website's design.

Here is the html code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Log In" id="button-log" />
```

Here is the css code:

```
#button-log {
width:70px;
height:30px;
background-color:#1963FF;
}
```

Nothin unusual here right?

But I really don't know why the Log In text appears down in Firefox, but not in Opera.

If anyone helps I'd really be greatful.

Comment: What versions of Firefox and Opera? I'm not seeing any difference aside from the black border around the button in Opera...

Comment: Classic headache. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679952/input-type-submit-text-vertical-alignment-in-firefox

Comment: Are you using a css reset? I suggest you check out http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/. It helps with input types to make them more consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
#button-log {
    width:70px;
    height:30px;
    padding:3px 0;
    background-color:#1963FF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `line-height` in button CSS

```
#button-log {
    line-height:24px; // or you can adjust accord to your need
    width:70px;
    height:30px;
    padding:3px 0;
    background-color:#1963FF;
}
```