# Input submit and "a" tag styling to look identical - Firefox issue

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to get a button (input) and a link to look identical on my page, but I am having some alignment issues in Firefox. This is the HTML:

```
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create New User" />
    <a class="linkButton" href="/Admin">Cancel and Return to User Index</a>
</p>
```

I am using the following CSS:

```
.linkButton, .linkButton:link, .linkButton:visited, input[type="submit"], input[type="button"] {
    background-color: #4AACC5;
    border: 1px solid #4A77C4;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 27px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
    font: inherit;
}
```

With the above setup everything works ok in Chrome, but in Firefox I have the two elements not aligned:

[image: Misaligned Buttons]

You can check this fiddle with both FF and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/hqJDZ/5/

Now, I would like a solution that would NOT involve using `a` in both cases with something like `onclick="javascript:submit();"`. The Views are scaffolded and work nicely so I would prefer a pure HTML/CSS solution.

You may note I have not mentioned IE... I just don't want to go there for the time being :P

Comment: `line-height` probably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this might be your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986666/107244

```
input::-moz-focus-inner /*Remove button padding in FF*/
{ 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but at first this was not working and now it is... maybe it's just v22 that fixed things... I'll accept at least until it holds :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add two attributes in your class:

```
Display:block;
float:left;
```